# LaTeX rendering broken on iPhone

Tags: bug, status-norepro, mathjax

This is related to [a previous question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/524/13854), but that question is marked (status-completed), so something new must have happened.

I was able to read MathJax on my iPhone a week ago, but now when I try to read Math.SE, I get the aforementioned [Math Processing Error]. Has something changed recently?

Comment: Works fine here. $\text{As you cannot see... :-)}$

Comment: I logged out of SE and then rebooted Safari (before, I had simply restarted Safari) and now MathJax is rendering. It logged me off of SE on my laptop as well, but at least things are working. Hopefully, this may help others for whom LaTeX rendering ceases to function.

Comment: And did you update to iOS5 in the past week?

Comment: Happening to me too... I haven't upgraded to iOS5 yet... I guess if it's necessary I will, but I'm a bit lazy.

Comment: @GEdgar: I have not yet upgraded to iOS5. However, as I mentioned, I was able to get MathJax rendering again by logging out of StackExchange.com before restarting Safari.

Comment: Since you fixed it, should we close this question?

Comment: @GEdgar: I will close it. I saw that aengle seems to have had the same problem so I was waiting to see if the same thing worked for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can't reproduce this. Are you still seeing an issue with MathJax your iPhone?

Comment: No, I have not gotten a [Math Processing Error] in a long time.  Once in a while a few characters render as boxes, but usually that goes away when I restart the browser.